How to match a Shadow Figma design to a Flutter desing?
I have the following component in Figma:

With the following CSS code:
/* Frame 1000004339 */

box-sizing: border-box;

/* Auto layout */
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: flex-end;
padding: 4px;
gap: 12px;

width: 355px;
height: 60px;

background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px rgba(12, 0, 56, 0.48);
backdrop-filter: blur(32px);
/* Note: backdrop-filter has minimal browser support */
border-radius: 30.2573px;

/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 0;
flex-grow: 0;


/* Frame 1000004338 */

/* Auto layout */
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 14px;
gap: 10px;

margin: 0 auto;
width: 52px;
height: 52px;

/* Primary Alt */
background: linear-gradient(271.66deg, #2E1EEA 0%, #3A8FF2 100%);
border-radius: 80px;

/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 0;
flex-grow: 0;


/* ri:home-fill */

width: 24px;
height: 24px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 0;
flex-grow: 0;


/* Vector */

position: absolute;
left: 12.5%;
right: 12.5%;
top: 9.44%;
bottom: 12.5%;

background: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 22px;


/* Frame 1000004338 */

/* Auto layout */
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 14px;
gap: 10px;

margin: 0 auto;
width: 52px;
height: 52px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 1;
flex-grow: 0;


/* solar:map-bold */

width: 24px;
height: 24px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 0;
flex-grow: 0;


/* Vector */

position: absolute;
left: 8.33%;
right: 8.33%;
top: 8.78%;
bottom: 8.77%;

background: rgba(30, 14, 95, 0.38);


/* Frame 1000004338 */

/* Auto layout */
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 14px;
gap: 10px;

margin: 0 auto;
width: 52px;
height: 52px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 2;
flex-grow: 0;


/* fluent:chat-16-filled */

width: 24px;
height: 24px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 0;
flex-grow: 0;


/* Vector */

position: absolute;
left: 12.49%;
right: 12.51%;
top: 12.5%;
bottom: 12.5%;

background: rgba(30, 14, 95, 0.38);


/* Frame 1000004338 */

/* Auto layout */
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 14px;
gap: 10px;

margin: 0 auto;
width: 52px;
height: 52px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 3;
flex-grow: 0;


/* mingcute:calendar-fill */

width: 24px;
height: 24px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 0;
flex-grow: 0;


/* Group */

position: absolute;
left: 12.5%;
right: 12.5%;
top: 12.5%;
bottom: 0.78%;



/* Vector */

position: absolute;
left: 50.32%;
right: 46.2%;
top: 96.44%;
bottom: 0.77%;



/* Vector */

position: absolute;
left: 12.5%;
right: 12.5%;
top: 12.5%;
bottom: 12.5%;

background: rgba(30, 14, 95, 0.38);


/* Frame 1000004338 */

/* Auto layout */
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: flex-start;
padding: 14px;
gap: 10px;

margin: 0 auto;
width: 52px;
height: 52px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 4;
flex-grow: 0;


/* iconamoon:profile-fill */

width: 24px;
height: 24px;


/* Inside auto layout */
flex: none;
order: 0;
flex-grow: 0;


/* Vector */

position: absolute;
left: 12.5%;
right: 12.5%;
top: 12.5%;
bottom: 12.5%;

background: rgba(30, 14, 95, 0.38);

But it dose not matter how many times I've tried to match this exact design, I can not do it.
Flutter code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart' show SvgPicture;

class NavigationState with ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  int get currentIndex => _currentIndex;

  void navigateTo(int index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class NavBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final Function(int) onItemSelected;

  final Color shadowColor = const Color(0xFF0C0038);

  const NavBarPage({super.key, required this.index, required this.onItemSelected});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return RepaintBoundary(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
        child: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.08),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.07)),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              // boxShadow: [
              //   BoxShadow(
              //       color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.48), blurRadius: 20, spreadRadius: 0, blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer),
              // ],
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: shadowColor.withOpacity(0.48),
                  blurRadius: 20,
                  spreadRadius: 0,
                  offset: const Offset(4, 4),
                  blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: List.generate(
                  5,
                  (buttonIndex) => NavButton(
                        iconPath: getIconPathIndex(buttonIndex),
                        isActive: index == buttonIndex,
                        onTap: () => onItemSelected(buttonIndex),
                      )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String getIconPathIndex(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return 'assets/icons/home.svg';
      case 1:
        return 'assets/icons/map.svg';
      case 2:
        return 'assets/icons/chat.svg';
      case 3:
        return 'assets/icons/calendar.svg';
      case 4:
        return 'assets/icons/profile.svg';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
}

class NavButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String iconPath;
  final bool isActive;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const NavButton({super.key, required this.iconPath, this.isActive = false, required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    const double buttonSize = 52;

    final Color primaryColor = theme.colorScheme.primary;
    final Color secondaryColor = theme.colorScheme.secondary;
    final bool isLightTheme = theme.brightness == Brightness.light;

    Color nonActiveColor = isLightTheme
        ? theme.colorScheme.onSurface // Light theme color
        : Colors.white; // Dark theme color
    return RepaintBoundary(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Container(
          width: buttonSize,
          height: buttonSize,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            gradient: isActive
                ? LinearGradient(
                    colors: [secondaryColor, primaryColor],
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  )
                : null,
            color: isActive ? null : Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: Center(
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
            iconPath,
            colorFilter: isActive
                ? const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.srcIn)
                : ColorFilter.mode(nonActiveColor.withOpacity(0.38), BlendMode.srcIn),
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

How can I match the shadow exactly as it is here in the design?
